# Using purchased prefabs in Unity's UI Toolkit (ui builder)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, prefab

I'm **brand new** to Unity, so excuse the likely dumb question, but I can't find any tutorials about this.

I've purchased a UI pack from the Unity asset store, and am trying to set up a user interface using the prefab buttons that came with it.

In the UI builder, I have no problem adding buttons and styling them, but how do I use the prefab buttons? I've imported all of it into the project and they exist in the Assets folder, but I don't have a clue on how to use them. Thanks a ton for your help!

Edit: can .prefab files not be used in the UI BUilder? Maybe I need to use the old Canvas method of UI for these to work?

Comment: prefabs suggest they are for the "old" stype UI (which frankly i prefer)